# Use UserControls multipletimes with different UserControl name & data

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, datacontext

So with a little help of the internet I establish nice GUI content (thank you Google :)) where I can change between different UserControl in one ContentControl with help of ComboBox. So because I am pretty fresh in WPF think I have some question for you guys and girls.

When program start its refresh Combobox items with all the Views. I can add same view as many times I wish. Code of "Main" window ViewModel:

ConfigurationDialog.xaml (Main Window) code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:GeneralSettingsViewModel}">
        <View:GeneralSettingsView/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:AdvancedSettingsViewModel}">
        <View:AdvancedSettingsView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxMenu" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" Height="20" ItemsSource="{Binding Settings}" SelectedIndex="0">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Padding="10"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>

    <Border Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" BorderBrush="#FF7F9DB9" BorderThickness="1">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=ComboBoxMenu, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
    </Border>

</Grid>
```

Code in ConfigurationDialogViewModel:

```
public class ConfigurationDialogViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<SettingsViewModelBase> settings;

    public ObservableCollection<SettingsViewModelBase> Settings
    {
        get { return this.settings; }
    }

    public ConfigurationDialogViewModel()
    {
        this.settings = new ObservableCollection<SettingsViewModelBase>();



        this.settings.Add(new GeneralSettingsViewModel());
        this.settings.Add(new AdvancedSettingsViewModel());
        this.settings.Add(new GeneralSettingsViewModel());
    }
}
```

So there I establish two times "GeneralSettingsViewModel()" and it is working nice like that. Only thing what I dont like is always the same name. In my case it show two time "General Settings" name. I like to have "General Settings 1" and "General Settings 2" etc. Code of GeneralSettingsViewModel:

```
public class GeneralSettingsViewModel : SettingsViewModelBase
{
    public override string Name
    {
        get { return "General"; }
    }
}

public abstract class SettingsViewModelBase : ViewModelBase
{
    public abstract string Name { get; }
}
```

Later when for example "General Settings 1" is choosen and data inputet, I like it that is not more "General Settings 1" available, so how to removed from ComboBox exaly that item.

So is possible to manual generate name of item in combobox in "Main Window" ViewModel (in my case "ConfigurationDialogViewModel") and how later to remove it? Also between I must captured inputet date of UserControl.

View one of the UserControls:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ConfigurationDialogExample.View.GeneralSettingsView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="General settings" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

If any question please ask. Sorry if "wrong" question is asked (I am new in WPF).

Answer (score 0):

OK. I solve it I think:

MainWindow ViewModel Code:

```
public ConfigurationDialogViewModel()
    {
        this.settings = new ObservableCollection<SettingsViewModelBase>();

        GeneralSettingsViewModel GeneralSettings1 = new GeneralSettingsViewModel();
        GeneralSettingsViewModel GeneralSettings2 = new GeneralSettingsViewModel();
        GeneralSettingsViewModel GeneralSettings3 = new GeneralSettingsViewModel();
        AdvancedSettingsViewModel AdvancedSettingsViewModel1 = new AdvancedSettingsViewModel();
        AdvancedSettingsViewModel AdvancedSettingsViewModel2 = new AdvancedSettingsViewModel();
        AdvancedSettingsViewModel AdvancedSettingsViewModel3 = new AdvancedSettingsViewModel();

        GeneralSettings1.Name = "keks1";
        GeneralSettings2.Name = "keks2";
        GeneralSettings3.Name = "keks3";

        AdvancedSettingsViewModel1.Name = "banana1";
        AdvancedSettingsViewModel2.Name = "banana2";
        AdvancedSettingsViewModel3.Name = "banana3";

        this.settings.Add(GeneralSettings1);
        this.settings.Add(GeneralSettings2);
        this.settings.Add(GeneralSettings3);
        this.settings.Add(AdvancedSettingsViewModel1);
        this.settings.Add(AdvancedSettingsViewModel2);
        this.settings.Add(AdvancedSettingsViewModel3);



    }
```

MainWindow View Code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxMenu" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" Height="20" ItemsSource="{Binding Settings}" SelectedIndex="0">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Padding="10"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>

    <Border Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" BorderBrush="#FF7F9DB9" BorderThickness="1">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=ComboBoxMenu, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
    </Border>

</Grid>
```

One of UserControl Code:

```
public class AdvancedSettingsViewModel : SettingsViewModelBase
{
    public override string Name
    {
        get; set;
    }


}
```